# Hi , I need help for university task. I can`t get head of one table and it says "'list' object has no attribute 'head'"

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
url="https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C"
syte=pd.read_html(url, match="Коефіцієнт народжуваності в регіонах України",  thousands=".", decimal=",")
syte.head()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-4753ce7c8445> in <module>
----> 1 syte.head()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'
```

I parsed table from wikipedia and tryed to get a head of that table but pandas shows me error

Comment: As [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) says, `read_html` returns a list of `DataFrame` objects. Lists don't have a `head` method.

Answer (score 2):

[`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) returns always a *list* even if the number of tables `==` 1. You need to perform indexing and use `[0]` to retrieve the first *element/dataframe* of this list.

> `pandas.read_html` : Read HTML tables into **a list of DataFrame** objects.

```
syte= pd.read_html(url, match="Коефіцієнт народжуваності в регіонах України",
                   thousands=".", decimal=",")[0]
```

​
Output :

```
print(syte.head())

             Регіон  1950  1960  1970  1990  2000  2012  2014  2019
0              Крим  23.0  20.6  16.0  13.0   7.3  12.6     —     —
1         Вінницька  22.4  19.2  14.2  12.4   8.4  11.2  10.9   7.6
2         Волинська  24.7  25.0  17.9  15.3  11.2  14.8  14.1  10.1
3  Дніпропетровська  20.4  20.4  15.1  12.3   7.1  11.2  11.1   7.1
4          Донецька  27.1  21.4  14.0  10.9   6.1   9.8   8.2     —
```

Comment: To supplement what @Timeless said. 
The list object does not have a head attribute. Lists are collections of objects, and they do not have a head or any other specific attribute.
try this: syte[0].head()

Comment: Right after the slice, you can call `head()` without any problem.

Comment: Technically not a slice. Slicing a list results in a list. This is just simple item access by index.

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake because indexing and slicing are not really the same thing. Answer updated, thank you so much @kindall ;)